# why overload member function access tuple and recurse accumulate result fail?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enable-if

I want to access tuple member and accumulate  result next and next. but not work and it look as access out-of-bound(invalid use of incomplete type `struct std::tuple_element<0u, std::tuple<> >`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename...ARGS>
struct NextTest
{
    std::tuple<ARGS...> data;
    template<std::size_t I,bool=I<sizeof...(ARGS)>
    struct Dispatch{};
    template<std::size_t I,typename T>
    T next3(T t,Dispatch<I,false>)const
    {
        return t;
    }
    template<std::size_t I,typename T>
    auto next3(T t,Dispatch<I,true>)const->decltype(this->next3<I+1>(std::get<I>(data),Dispatch<I+1>{}))
    {

        return this->next3<I+1>(std::get<I>(data),Dispatch<I+1>{});
    }
    template<std::size_t I,typename T>
    auto next3(T t)const->decltype(this->next3<I>(t,Dispatch<I>{}))
    {
        return this->next3<I>(t,Dispatch<I>{});
    }
    template<std::size_t I,typename T,typename std::enable_if<(I>=sizeof...(ARGS))>::type* =nullptr>
    T next(T t)const
    {
        return t;
    }
    template<std::size_t I,typename T,typename std::enable_if<(I<sizeof...(ARGS))>::type* =nullptr>
    auto next(T t)const->decltype(this->next<I+1>(std::get<I>(data)))
    {

        return this->next<I+1>(std::get<I>(data));
    }
    template<std::size_t I,typename std::enable_if<(I>=sizeof...(ARGS))>::type* =nullptr>
    void next2()const
    {
        std::cout<<"end!";
    }
    template<std::size_t I,typename std::enable_if<(I<sizeof...(ARGS))>::type* =nullptr>
    void next2()const
    {
        std::cout<<"in seq ";
        next2<I+1>();
    }

};
void testexpr1()
{
    NextTest<int> nt;
    nt.next<0>( 1);//fail
nt.next3<0>( 1);//fail
nt.next2<0>();//pass!
}
```

mingw gcc 4.8.1  why error? and  what should I do?

**update1:**this complie out:

```
...\include\c++\tuple||In instantiation of 'struct std::tuple_element<1u, std::tuple<int> >':|
...\include\c++\tuple|771|  required by substitution of 'template<unsigned int __i, class ... _Elements> constexpr typename std::__add_r_ref<typename std::tuple_element<__i, std::tuple<_Elements ...> >::type>::type std::get(std::tuple<_Elements ...>&&) [with unsigned int __i = 1u; _Elements = {int}]'|
...\test.cpp|83|  required by substitution of 'template<unsigned int I, class T> decltype (this->.next1<(I + 1)>(get<I>(this->.data))) NextTest<ARGS>::next1(T&, typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (ARGS ...))>::type*) [with unsigned int I = I; T = T; ARGS = {int}] [with unsigned int I = 1u; T = <missing>]'|
...\test.cpp|83|  required by substitution of 'template<unsigned int I, class T> decltype (this->.next1<(I + 1)>(get<I>(this->.data))) NextTest<ARGS>::next1(T&, typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (ARGS ...))>::type*) [with unsigned int I = I; T = T; ARGS = {int}] [with unsigned int I = 0u; T = int]'|
...\test.cpp|104|required from here|
...\include\c++\tuple|680|error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::tuple_element<0u, std::tuple<> >'|
...\include\c++\utility|84|error: declaration of 'struct std::tuple_element<0u, std::tuple<> >'|
```

Comment: When posting question about compiler or linker errors, please include the *complete* and *unedited* error log in the question. Also mark out the lines in the provided source where the errors are, or it will be hard to find them.

Comment: `-> decltype(this->next<I+1>(std::get<I>(data)))`. As far as I recall, `this` cannot be used in this context, in the trailing-return-type. (I'm not sure which is why I'm not posting it as answer)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  sorry ,because error be truncated and little help

Comment: Also, **if** `this` is available in the context of trailing-return-type **and** it is not *implicit*, then you've to qualify `data` with `this` as well. So write `this->data` instead of just `data` in : `decltype(this->next<I+1>(std::get<I>(data)))`.

Comment: @Nawaz if not use `this->` even `std::get<I>` change to `std::get<0>` will fail.use `this->`  `return this->next<I+1>(std::get<0>(data));` will pass! this is the other one confused...

Comment: Your posted error is **nonsense**. Either you've edited the code, or the error because it shows `next1` in the error *this->. **next1** <(I + 1)>(get<I>(this->.data))*.... whereas I don't see `next1` in the code! Please DONT WASTE others time by posting nonsense!

Comment: @Nawaz `this` in the trailing-return-type of a non-static member function is fine.

Comment: I wonder if this is a problem of order of substitution. Also, I'm not sure if the function template `next` is guaranteed to be found in its own trailing-return-type. (I know that's a problem for free functions, not sure about member function declarations.)

Comment: In fact, `template<std::size_t I,typename T>
    auto next(T t)const->decltype(typename std::enable_if<(I<sizeof...(ARGS)), int>::type{}, this->next<I+1>(std::get<I>(data)))` seems to work. I therefore *think* it has to do with order of substitution, though I'm not 100 % sure.

Comment: Huh? It seems to work even with `template<std::size_t I,typename std::enable_if<(I<sizeof...(ARGS))>::type*,typename T>` when explicitly specifying `nullptr` as the second template argument.

Comment: @Nawaz sorry error info's next1 is next ,I change many time so not orrespond.

Comment: @fe263 OK, [here's a minimal, complete example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59f03ade979c5c78) that reproduces the problem. You might want to add this to your question.

Comment: @dyp : yes `enalbe_if` put second and `next<0,nullptr>` work! and no ,`enable_if` not work if put  in `decltype`...your complier?

Comment: o.O `enable_if` inside `decltype` works in clang++, but not in g++. This smells like a compiler bug (of g++). That is doesn't work when using the default template argument seems to me also like a compiler bug, considering http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1227

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two errors in the code:

- One is as @Nawaz mentioned this-> is required in the decltype section to access member functions and member variables (at least in gcc 4.7.2).
- The second is a [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) in accessing the tuple elements (see where 'I' is changed to 'I+1' in the enable_if meta-function calls and the default argument in the Dispatch struct).

After fixing these two issues the code compiles fine on gcc 4.7.2.

Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename...ARGS>
struct NextTest
{
    std::tuple<ARGS...> data;

    template<std::size_t I,bool=(I+1)<sizeof...(ARGS)>
    struct Dispatch{};

    template<std::size_t I,typename T>
    T next3(T t,Dispatch<I,false>)const
    {
        return t;
    }
    template<std::size_t I,typename T>
    auto next3(T t,Dispatch<I,true>)const->decltype(this->next3<I+1>(std::get<I>(this->data),Dispatch<I+1>{}))
    {
        return this->next3<I+1>(std::get<I>(data),Dispatch<I+1>{});
    }
    template<std::size_t I,typename T>
    auto next3(T t)const->decltype(this->next3<I>(t,Dispatch<I>{}))
    {
        return this->next3<I>(t,Dispatch<I>{});
    }

    template<std::size_t I,typename T,typename std::enable_if<((I+1)>=sizeof... (ARGS))>::type* =nullptr>
    T next(T t)const
    {
        return t;
    }
    template<std::size_t I,typename T,typename std::enable_if<((I+1)<sizeof...(ARGS))>::type* =nullptr>
    auto next(T t)const->decltype(this->next<I+1>(std::get<I>(this->data)))
    {
        return this->next<I+1>(std::get<I>(data));
    }

    template<std::size_t I,typename std::enable_if<((I+1)>=sizeof...(ARGS))>::type* =nullptr>
    void next2()const
    {
        std::cout<<"end!";
    }
    template<std::size_t I,typename std::enable_if<((I+1)<sizeof...(ARGS))>::type* =nullptr>
    void next2()const
    {
        std::cout<<"in seq ";
        next2<I+1>();
    }
};

void testexpr1()
{
    NextTest<int> nt;
    nt.next<0>( 1);//pass
    nt.next3<0>( 1);//pass
    nt.next2<0>();//pass!
}
```

Comment: I do not think there is an off-by-one error. Yes, the code compiles if you add one there, but if the tuple has size 1, then `next<1>` won't be called with your code, even though it is valid (I'm not quite sure what the OP has intended, though). You can also make it compile by using the OP's code but pass the `nullptr` explicitly instead of relying on default template arguments.